# running build.xml from java project

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run ant script from java project which, in turn, I have to make it as excutable jar file
here is the way I have done:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /c start ant.bat  -buildfile D:\\ant\\trail\\build.xml")
```

But I don't want to give full path for build.xml. Instead, I want it to take from current source directory.

I tried something like this

```
rt.exec("cmd /c start ant.bat  -buildfile .\build.xml");
```

but I get an error showing that `cannot find build.xml, build failed`

Comment: sorry Alex,iam new to stack overflow iam still learning how to use it

Comment: No problem. There is always time to learn. Just go to your user page, review your previous questions and accept (via clicking big checkmark to the left of answer) answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative directory in java program doesn't start from the src folder, but from the projects (in Eclipse) or the jar folder. Make sure you have the file in the correct path. Also, don't forget to escape the slash:

```
rt.exec("cmd /c start ant.bat  -buildfile .\\build.xml");
```

Comment: hey this one seems to work while running from eclipse ide, but when i export it as runnable jar the build.xml is not exported to the package.Also the build.xml file is present in the project home directory and not in any package.